# How to write a single cell nr into multiple cells but with set place of end nr. in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need advice on how to get a single cell nr. into multiple ones but so they don't change end position.
For example
A1=100.21 A2=1 A3=0 A4=0  A5=.  A6=2  A7=1
But if the nr is bigger or lower then the positions don't change and stay
A1=10.21 A2=""  A3=1 A4=0  A5=.  A6=2  A7=1

Comment: I need opposite of combineing. I need to separate one nr. into separate digits. (100 to 1 and 0 and 0)

Comment: nr = number?  I mean, it's fairly obvious you're referring to a number but not immediately obvious.  I initially thought it meant _near_ but then the heading made no sense so opened the question to look.....  make sense now, but don't know he answer.

Comment: This'll split it into single cells:  `=MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)`, not sure about the lining up though.

Comment: You'll need to decide (or know), beforehand, the format of the value in A1. Otherwise, when you change that value, your functions will have no way of knowing how to split it up to maintain the consistency you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have overcomplicated it but now it works. First I have a cell where you write a number. For example A1.

Then I used `=MID($A$1;COLUMNS($A$1:A$1);1)` to get every digit individually.

On the third row, I marked the positions of the numbers `C2=1, C3=2, C4=3`, etc.
Because my numbers are prices it always contains a (.) so in the second row I used `B2=FIND(".";A2), B3=FIND(".";A3)`, etc.

Now all I needed was an IF function, based on the position of the (.)
If anyone needs an excel example I can create one.